# Single line AND statement in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is a simple way to do an AND statement in a SINGLE line?

```
example:

if %turn2%== 1
and
if %ttt1%== 1
set ttt1=X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `AND`, AFAIK. To make sure both conditions are met, simply place them one after the other:

```
REM The next line echos 
if "1"=="1" if "2"=="2" echo Equal 
REM This one does not
if "1"=="1" if "2"=="3"  echo Equal again
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that with more than 2 "if"s?

Comment: @Cody: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work;
    if "%ttt1%"=="X" if "%ttt2%"=="X" if "%ttt3%"=="3"  (set ttt3=O) & goto :TTTP2

Comment: If you try it with the sample I posted, it works fine. What makes you think it's the third `if` that isn't working? Why do your first two match "X" and your third "3"? What does "doesn't appear to work" mean?

Comment: You're ignoring everything I asked you. I don't know how you expect me to help you if you won't provide the information I ask you to provide. I can't see your screen from here, and my psychic abilities can't reach quite that far. :)

Comment: Sorry. ttt1=1 and ttt2=2 by default; should they both get changed to "X", I want "ttt3" to change from "3" to "O", but only if "ttt3" is "3". I doesn't appear to work b/c "ttt3" isn't changing to "O" when it should. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's not an issue with the `if` not working. That's an issue with the variable not changing value. IOW, that's a totally different topic (and question). Multiple `if` statements work fine, as you can see if you copy my working example and add a third `if` statement: `if "1"=="1" if "2"=="2" if "3"=="3" echo Three pairs` works just fine.